# Difference between the docker run --tty and --interactive switches

Tags: python, docker

I feel there is a subtle difference between the `--tty` and `--interactive` switches of the `docker run` command, that I don't grasp:

- `--interactive`, `-i`: Keep STDIN open even if not attached
- `--tty` , `-t`: Allocate a pseudo-TTY

So I decided to run some tests.
First I created a basic Python script, which continuously prints a string.
Then I created a basic docker image, which will run this script when a container is started.

*my_script.py*

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('still running...')
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.8.1-buster
COPY my_script.py /
CMD [ "python3", "/my_script.py"]
```

*Built using command:*

```
docker build --tag pytest .
```

**Test 1**
I run `docker run --name pytest1 -i pytest`, to test the interactive behaviour of the container.
Nothing is printed to the console, but when I press `Control+C` the python script is interrupted and the container stops running.

This confirms my thinking that stdin was open on the container and my keyboard input entered the container.

**Test 2**
I run `docker run --name pytest1 -t pytest`, to test the pseudo-tty behaviour of the container. It repeatedly prints `still running...` to the console, ánd when I press `Control+C` the python script is interrupted and the container stops running.

**Test 3**
I run `docker run --name pytest1 -it pytest`, to test the combined behaviour. The behaviour is the same as in Test 2.

**Questions**

- What are the nuances I'm missing here?
- Why would one use the combined `-it` switches, as you often see, if there is no benefit to the `-t` switch?
- Does the `--tty` switch just keeps bóth stdin and stdout open?

Answer (score 7):

`-t` option is needed if you want to interact with a shell like /bin/sh for instance. The shell works by controlling tty. No tty available, no shell.

we use `-i` in combination with `-t` to be able to write commands to the shell we opened

few tests you could reproduce to understand:

`docker run alpine /bin/sh`: the container exits. shell needs to wait for stdin

`docker run -i alpine /bin/sh`: the container stays, but the shell won't start. we cannot type commands

`docker run -t alpine /bin/sh`: shell starts, but we are stuck, the keys we press are not interpreted

`docker run -it alpine /bin/sh` : yeah our shell is working